# Google Closure XhrIo

Tags: json, google-closure

I am new to Google Closure and I would like to know on how XhrIo works. I have read the overview of XHRIO http://code.google.com/closure/library/docs/xhrio.html

basically, I am following the example but I just can't make it work. I am using eclipse and tomcat as my server to perform the example. Can someone please enlighten me on just how to make the connection between html, the java script that uses the goog.require('goog.net.XhrIo'); and the json file? Thank you guys.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a sample to make a post request:

```
goog.require('goog.Uri');
goog.require('goog.net.XhrIo');

var qd = new goog.Uri.QueryData(); 
qd.add('name1', 'val1'); 
qd.add('name2', 'val2'); 
function done(e) { 
   this.getResponseText();
   this.getResponseJson();
}  
goog.net.XhrIo.send('/controller/action', done, 'POST', qd.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks Maxence for the help although I was expecting the most simple and basic way. I did manage to do it. Your example code will be a good help on my next level of learning. Thank you very much